# One of project frequently needs cache clear in development

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-8, laravel-valet

I have a problem on my local development for only one project. One of the project keeps cache. Almost everytime i have to run php artisan route:clear when i modify web.php, and sometimes when i change the controller or model, i have to run php artisan cache:clear to see changes.

That happens only one of my laravel project. Other project doesnt require those processes.

laravel version is 8.83.18

And i use laravel valet for development environment.

Is there any idea about what may causes that problem?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: May be there is `Artisan::call('config:cache')` or  `Artisan::call('optimize')` code which run every/certain request.

Comment: Could you explain a little with more details?

Comment: In Laravel, usually `ServiceProvider` or `Middleware` is  run on every request. So if we put artisan command code in these file/other files, it will cache the all configuration settings. I think these are the reasons.

Comment: You have to share some code of the affected routes. Generally for development and testing you can use a 0 expiry for the cache items or use a cache driver that does not persist.

Comment: As i mentioned, its not about a specific route. It doesn't detect any changes in web.php. Using a cache driver that doesnt persist is a good idea. I have created a driver as name none with null value in cache.php and changed the value of CACHE_DRIVER to none in .env file. For now, it seems to be working well. Thank you.